# flexbox justify-self: flex-end not working?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout where *sometimes* the 'left' item is missing. In such cases, I still want the 'right' item to be right-aligned.

I thought I could do this with `justify-self` but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there a flexbox property for right-aligning one's self?

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--<div class="left">left</div>-->
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You could use `margin-left: auto` on `right` element instead. Also when you use `display: flex` on parent element `display: inline-block` on child elements is not going to work.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.left,
.right {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <!--<div class="left">left</div>-->
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin: auto not responsive as i tested

Comment: To add to this answer, `justify-self` is simply not supported in flexbox because it justifies all its items as a group. More info here (along with the margin tip):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment/Box_Alignment_in_Flexbox

Comment: I created a pen to emulate this: https://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/abNLGgr

Comment: margin-left / margin-right did not work to split them for me - it centered them instead.

Comment: An alternative to `margin-left: auto` is having `justify-content: space-between` on the parent (assuming there are only two children).