# css flexbox justify-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a horizontal bar made from `flexbox`.

If there are **2 or more items**, I want each items separated as far as possible, so I set `justify-content: space-between`.

But if there is **only 1 item**, I want the item placed at the end, so I set `justify-content: flex-end`.

The items are ordered from left to right. So setting `flex-direction: row-reverse` wouldn't work.

How I combine the first, second & third terms? The items are dynamically added/removed.

Comment: You can use JS to dynamically  add your styles based on the no. of items

Comment: You can't really do this with `flexbox`. If you are dynamically generating the content, you could add a class to the wrapping element to denote a single element and use `justify-content: flex-end`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658425/flexbox-justify-self-flex-end-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage `:only-child`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .25em;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  background: pink;
}

.item:only-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: great idea using margin-left:auto, but i prefer use margin-inline-start:auto. If the page's orientation rotated 90deg, the left become top. The margin-inline-start are rotation proof than margin-left.

Comment: @YunusKurniawan no IE support altho IE is deprecated but lots of companies still support it

Comment: just declare twice as fallback

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `+` which selects the next sibling. This method uses `justify-content: flex-end`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: grey;
}

.item+.item {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="flex">

  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

OR

You can also target the first child with `:first-child:last-child` which allows you to set this up a different way. This method uses `justify-content: space-between`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.item:first-child:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="flex">

  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Paulie_D

The idea is using combination `margin-left` (or `margin-inline-start`) and `:first-child:last-child` (the only child).

I was spent a hours for solving this problem without success. Now works!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use `justify-self: flex-end;` on the first item

```
.items {
    justify-content: space-between;
    .item:first-of-type {
        justify-self: flex-end;
    }
}
```

Comment: `justify-self` does not work for flexbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658425/flexbox-justify-self-flex-end-not-working

Comment: use `display: grid;` or JS is the best way

Comment: It's fairly easy to do with flex

Comment: With angular : `<div class="items" [ngStyle]="justify-content: items.length > 1 ? 'space-between' : 'flex-end'" >`